# graphX cannot graph multiple Edges and Vertices?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

my vertice type is:

`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((Long, String), (Long, String), (Long, String))]`

my edge type is:

`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[String],org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[String])]`

When I tried to Graph(vertices, edges).

It's saying:

```
<console>:47: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((Long, String), (Long, String), (Long, String))]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, ?)]

<console>:47: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[String], org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[String])]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[?]]
```

(Long String) is tuple2.

Comment: What do you think you mean by ((Long, String), (Long,String), (Long,String))? Do you think you are declaring an `RDD` with three tuples as elements, or where each line in the `RDD` has 3 tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to correct both your vertex and edge rdd.

vertex rdd it is a rdd[(VertexId, vertexValueType)]

so you have to change your vertex rdd to:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(VertexId, ((Long, String), (Long, String), (Long, String)))]
```

and edge rdd it is a rdd[Edge[edgeValueType]]
so indeed it should be like this:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[String]]
```

Maybe you can post a code where you actually create this rdds?